# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server

I am running some scheduled jobs in SQL server and they were running fine until yesterday and gave me the error as given below.

Message

> Executed as user: GONDWANA\svc_kib_sql01. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   3:55:44 PM  Error: 2019-12-24 15:56:00.43     Code: 0xC0202009
>   Source: ProdBlockImportOP_CSV Connection manager "DataShed_Database"
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server [53]. ".  End Error  Error: 2019-12-24 15:56:00.43     Code:
>   0xC00291EC     Source: Create Temp Import Table
>   (tblProdBlockImport_OP) Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to
>   acquire connection "DataShed_Database". Connection may not be
>   configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:55:44 PM  Finished: 3:56:00 PM 
>   Elapsed:  17.125 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step
>   failed.

Could you please help me how to fix it?

Comment: Can you split the single paragraph into a more readable question using formatter?

Comment: What happens when you use Management Studio to connect manually to whatever `DataShed_Database` points to?

Comment: Even I am also facing same error. I am using SSMS-2016 on Win-16 server and connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) – 12.0.6372.1 (X64) database. I am running the SSIS package as flat file and it runs on local without any error. Only os serer it fails with error that says ***SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error Code: 0x80004005*** Can any expert here can point to some help, please?